# How to interpolate values to fill percentile ranges?

Tags: matlab

I have values for 10th-25th percentile range which is `0.49`, 25th-50th percentile is `1.36` (this is peak), 50th-75th percentile is `0.18`, >90th percentile is `0.15`.

I want to interpolate the values for the ranges >5, 5th-10th, 75th-90th percentile. How to do that in MATLAB?

If I assume a normal distribution, whose peak is `1.36` (25th-50th percentile) (as shown in figure attached), how to interpolate the values of unknown percentile ranges?

[image]

Comment: You should first think about the math behind this problem. How would you solve this problem with pencil and paper?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, performing an interpolation in order to find percentile values looks not very good to me. If you are dealing with a `normal distribution` and its parameters (`mu` and `sigma`) are known, what you are looking for is the `norminv` function (official documentation: https://mathworks.com/help/stats/norminv.html).

> X = norminv(P,mu,sigma) computes the inverse of the normal CDF using
>   the corresponding mean mu and standard deviation sigma at the
>   corresponding probabilities in P. The parameters in sigma must be
>   positive, and the values in P must lie in the interval [0 1].

For example, this is how you find the interval that contains 95% of the values of a standard normal distribution:

```
norminv([0.025 0.975],0,1)
```

This is how you find the 99th percentile of a normal distribution with `mu=10` and `sigma=3.5`:

```
norminv(0.99,10,3.5)
```

If you don't know those parameters, you can estimate them from the data you actually have. The parameters of the normal family are the `mean` and the `standard deviation`; once they are known, the underlying distribution is fully described. Actually:

- The `mean` of a normal distribution is halfway between the 25th and the 75th percentile. Average these two values to approximate it.
- In a normal distribution, the difference between the 25th and the 75th percentile is about 1.35 times its `standard deviation`. So take the difference between the aforementioned values and divide it by 1.35 in order to obtain an approximation of the `standard deviation`.

If you want to go with a `linear interpolation`, have a look at `interp1` (https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).